# Slick carousel with display:none slides and dots problem with dot count

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

So I have this to initialize a Slick carousel

```js
  $('.column').each(function () {
    const elementsContainer = $(this).find('.elements');

    if (elementsContainer.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
      elementsContainer.slick('unslick');
    }

    var slides = elementsContainer.children().not('.d-none');
    $(this).toggleClass('d-none', slides.length == 0);
    $(elementsContainer).toggleClass('d-none', slides.length == 0);

    if(slides.length > 0) {
      elementsContainer
        .slick({
          autoplay: false,
          dots: slides.length > 1,
          arrows: false,
          infinite: false,
          speed: 300,
          appendDots: $(this),
          dotsClass: 'dots',
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          swipeToSlide: slides.length > 1,
          draggable: slides.length > 1,
        })
        .slick('slickAdd', slides);
    }
  });
```

and the slider works fine. The only problem is, that the amount of dots that I get is always `elementsContainer.children().length` though it should be `slides.length` - meaning the dots also show up for those slides that have d-none and are not displayed, which I do not want.. These d-none slides can be anywhere in the elementsContainer...

Is there a sane way to only ensure dots for slides that do not have class `d-none` show up?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using `.slick('slickFilter', ':not(.d-none)');` instead of         `.slick('slickAdd', slides);`